# how to add a catch all SOAP error handler to a spring webservice?

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services, soap, error-handling

I have a spring application that takes in SOAP requests via a webservice and I want to set up a custom error handler that acts as a catch all error handler for any broken SOAP requests and return a generic message.

when the application gets a broken SOAP request sent by SOAP-Ui, am currently getting an error in my logs :

```
org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapMessageCreationException: Could not create message from InputStream: Not a valid SOAP Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; nested exception is oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.ContentTypeException: Not a valid SOAP Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:204)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:61)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.AbstractWebServiceConnection.receive(AbstractWebServiceConnection.java:89)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.support.WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.handleConnection(WebServiceMessageReceiverObjectSupport.java:86)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.handle(WebServiceMessageReceiverHandlerAdapter.java:60)
    at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.doService(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:288)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:631)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:287)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.handleErrorStatus(ErrorPageFilter.java:161)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:128)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3701)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3667)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2443)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2291)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2269)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1703)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1663)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)
Caused by: oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.ContentTypeException: Not a valid SOAP Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.internalCreateVersionedMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:383)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createVersionedMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:217)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createVersionedMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:212)
    at oracle.j2ee.ws.saaj.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:166)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory.createWebServiceMessage(SaajSoapMessageFactory.java:180)
    ... 49 common frames omitted
```

and as a response on soap Ui, i get :

```
      <env:Fault>
         <faultcode>env:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxParsingException: Unexpected close tag &lt;/apm:PIN>; expected &lt;/apm:record>.
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [8,45]</faultstring>
      </env:Fault>
```

I have tried to create my own exception handler and annotate it with soapfault for faultcore.server
but this does not appear to have been picked up by spring

```
@SoapFault(faultCode = FaultCode.SERVER)
public class simpleSoapErrorHandler extends Exception
{
    public simpleSoapErrorHandler(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

i get the impression there is something missing , i think am supposed to register the error handler somehow but am not sure how to approach it since all the configuration is done in spring-integration.xml

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that implements the `SoapFaultDefinitionExceptionResolver` interface. This class will serve as your custom SOAP error handler. Here's an example:

```java
public class CustomSoapFaultExceptionResolver extends AbstractEndpointExceptionResolver {

    private SoapFaultDefinition faultDefinition;

    public CustomSoapFaultExceptionResolver() {
        faultDefinition = new SoapFaultDefinition();
        faultDefinition.setFaultCode(SoapFaultDefinition.SERVER);
        faultDefinition.setFaultStringOrReason("Internal Server Error");
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean resolveExceptionInternal(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint, Exception ex) {
        SoapBody soapBody = messageContext.getResponse().getSoapBody();
        SoapFault fault = faultDefinition.getSoapFault(messageContext.getMessageFactory());
        SoapFaultDetail faultDetail = fault.addFaultDetail();
        SoapFaultDetailElement detailElement = faultDetail.addFaultDetailElement(QName.valueOf("error"));
        detailElement.addText("An error occurred while processing the request.");
        soapBody.addFault(fault);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Configure the custom SOAP error handler bean in your Spring configuration file (e.g., `applicationContext.xml` or `SpringBootApplicaton.java`). For example:

```java
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public CustomSoapFaultExceptionResolver 
    customSoapFaultExceptionResolver() {
        return new CustomSoapFaultExceptionResolver();
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
        interceptors.add(customSoapFaultExceptionResolver());
    }
}
```

With the custom error handler configured, any unhandled exceptions thrown during SOAP request processing will be caught by the `CustomSoapFaultExceptionResolver`. In the `resolveExceptionInternal` method, you can customize the SOAP fault definition and add additional details as needed
Note that the above example uses the Spring XML configuration approach. If you are using Spring Boot, you can adapt the configuration to use Java-based configuration or modify the `application.properties` file accordingly.